# How to implement Multiple Frames using nativescript-vue MultiDrawer?

Tags: nativescript-vue

I was using RadSideDrawer but now I wanted to try multidrawer.

repo readme file says...

```html
<MultiDrawer>
  <StackLayout slot="left">
    <Label text="Im in the left drawer" />  
  </StackLayout>

  <Frame /> <!-- main content goes into the default slot -->
</MultiDrawer>
```

### What is **the default slot**?

my **main.ts** file ...

```js
Vue.use(MultiDrawer)

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
}).$start()
```

While using RadSideDrawer I was adding menu to a component and adding menu to all other views.

All nativescript marketplace  uses `render: h => h('frame', [h(HelloWorld)])` accept [Playing with Shadows](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=roCIm3&v=149).

How to implement Multiple Frames if I need conditional navigation such as `render: h => h("frame", [h(backendService.isLoggedIn() ? routes.home : routes.login)])`

- Where should I add `<MultiDrawer>` tag?
- Where should I add  main content?
- Is there any demo project using multidrawer?

Comment: I there anyone using multidrawer as component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you actually need. The drawer itself is nothing more than a component that has up to 5 slots: `left, right, top, bottom and default`.

A `frame` is an element that is responsible for navigation, it keeps track of it's `backstack` and can be navigated to different pages and can manage the `backstack` with `clearHistory`, `backstackVisible`...

You can combine these depending on your needs. If you need a frame that navigates between the "logged out" pages (these don't need a drawer) and "logged in" pages, you have multiple options:

1. make the `MultiDrawer` your root element, and add a single frame to the `default` slot. Toggle if the drawer is enabled based on current location (this would need something like [`nativescript-vue-navigator`](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue-navigator) to keep track of the current "route").

```js
render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
```

is the same as

```html
<Frame>
  <App />
</Frame>
```

If I need to alter the root element, I usually change it to

```js
render: h => h(App)
```

And write all the elements inside the `App` component:

```html
<MultiDrawer :enabled="isLoggedIn">
  <!-- left slot left out but would go here -->

  <!-- a navigator in the default slot -->
  <Navigator :defaultRoute="isLoggedIn ? '/home' : '/login'"/>
</MultiDrawer>
```

2. Use multiple frames, one frame as the root frame, with an id like "authFrame".
   Navigate this frame for "logged out" auth pages, and a "logged in" Main page.
   On the Main page, add the `MultiDrawer`, and a second `Frame` as it's content in the `default` slot.

```html
  <!-- a pseudo code example of the structure, the different pages would be $navigateTo'd and not actually nested as child elements -->
  <Frame id="authFrame">
    <LoginPage/>
    <RegisterPage/>
    <MainPage>
      <MultiDrawer>
        <Frame/> <!-- the frame to navigate "logged in" pages -->
      </MultiDrawer>
    </MainPage>
  </Frame>
```

Comment: console log is full of `JS: [flush] serialized 29 instances.`

Comment: That's just VueDevtools.